# Unexpected output while executing an IIFE in .js file

Tags: javascript, function

I've been testing the following piece of code with a simple HTML document in my browser to get an output like
`50 > EVEN NUMBER .`
`75 > ODD NUMBER .`
`-1 > INVALID NUMBER .` in JavaScript dialog boxes. 
However, I get to see only the last one but not 3 separate dialog boxes. I'm eager to know why something like this is happening.

```
function isEven(X) {
    var number = X;
    var sol = (function find(number) {
                    if(number === 0) {
                        return 'Even';
                    } else if(number === 1) {
                        return 'Odd';
                    } else if(number > 1) {
                        find(number-2);
                    } else if(number < 0) {
                        return 'Invalid';
                    }
              }(number));

    switch(sol) {
        case 'Even': 
            alert(number+' is an '+'EVEN NUMBER .');
            break;
        case 'Odd': 
            alert(number+' is an '+'ODD NUMBER .');
            break;
        case 'Invalid': 
            alert(number+' is an '+'INVALID NUMBER .');
            break;
    }
} 

isEven(50);
isEven(75);
isEven(-1);
```

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging.

Comment: Trace through your program logic in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `find` recursively, but when you call `find(number-2);` you forgot to `return` anything. Consequently, the function returns `undefined` which doesn't match any case in your `switch`.

Comment: Eee...Yeah...You're right. I should have had that in mind. Thanks Quentin!